# Selenium search text in a page section and click on a button inside it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Webdriver and Java. My problem is that the page is splitted in 2 sections, both with the same name `//div[@class='sg-content-box sg-content-box--spaced']`

I want to click on the button `Aprobă` near the user David2211 (his answer can appear first or second)

My problem is that i don't know how to do click on the button in that specific area, for that specific username

[image]

Comment: Can you give me the site url please?

Comment: that's the site -> https://brainly.ro/ . Unfortunately you need admin privileges in order to see the buttons. If needed, i will create a test account.Thanks

Comment: Yes i will try my best. kindly give me a test account credentials

Comment: I have logged in but not able to see any buttons. Any other navigation after logging in?

Comment: then i will give you a direct link: https://brainly.ro/tema/4102259 .

Comment: Strange, I still can't find the `Aprobă` link :) from the direct link even. Thanks

Comment: Aproba it's not a link but the button.(if that's what you meant) from the right -top corner.

Comment: Got it in Chrome :) Thanks

Comment: @ctina, If any answer is helpful then please mark that answer as `accepted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For things like this, you have to use XPath since we are looking for an element that contains specific text. In this case, we will be looking for an element that contains the username 'David2211' and then a button that contains the text 'Aprobă'. I would assume that you will use this code more than once using different usernames so I would put this in a function so that it's easier to reuse.

The function

```
public void approveAnswerByUsername(String username)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'" + username
            + "')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'js-answer-element')]//div[contains(@class,'js-approve-button-text')][contains(.,'Aprobă')]")).click();
}
```

and you call it like

```
approveAnswerByUsername("David2211");
```

This XPath is rather large and complicated but it looks for an `A` tag that contains the specified username, goes up the DOM to find a parent `DIV` that encloses the entire answer and then navigates back down the DOM to find a `DIV` that contains the 'Aprobă' text.

Comment: can you please help me with another xpath that's on the same page? i have tryed different combinations and still i get the error  "unknown error:"

Comment: @ctina You will need to post a new question with all the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below xpath to locate the same element

Here you have to pass the user's name whose button you wants to click

```
//li/a[contains(.,'David2211')]/../../../preceding-sibling::div//button[@title='Aprobă']
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing specific to your button is indeed the username. I would suggest to get the xpath of the username's node, and then try to get its button from the parent's node using the xpath :

```
//{username's xpath}/parent::div[@class='sg-content-box sg-content-box--spaced']/{button's xpath}
```

It seems quite barbaric but that's the only way I see.

Answer (score 0):

A challenging xpath after many days. Thanks for asking this question. Try this below xpath.

```
"//li/a[contains(text(),'DemonBolt')]/ancestor::div[@class='sg-content-box sg-content-box--spaced']//div[@class='sg-label__text js-approve-button-text']"
```

or

```
 "//li/a[contains(text(),'DemonBolt')]/ancestor::div[@class='‌​sg-content-box sg-content-box--spaced']//div[contains(text(),'Aprobă')]"
```

Just change the text **DemonBolt** with the name whom you need to approve.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To click on the button `Aprobă` near the user `David2211` (his answer can appear anywhere) you can use the following code block:

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'David2211')]//preceding::button[2]/div/div[contains(text(),'Aproba')]"));
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
element.click();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.